# How to change size of PaintCode produced object

Tags: iphone, uislider, addtarget

I am a newbie, trying hard to make my first app. I would like to change the size of a (bezierpath) object(?) made by PaintCode by receiving a value from a UISlider. Can anyone help me what is wrong with my code below and how to make it work?

```
int heightOfBubble = 120;

- (IBAction)widthOfBubble:(id)sender {
NSLog(@"slider value = %f", self.slider.value);
[slider addTarget:self action:@selector(drawRect:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
}


- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", self.slider.value];
NSLog(@"slider value = %f", self.slider.value);
[BubbleText10 drawBubbleButtonWithText2:@"안개비 조명은 하예 흔들리는 내 몸을 감싸고~~ 술에 취에 비틀거리는 하~예 나의 모습 이제는 싫어~ 삐리비립" number:12 numberOfWidth:widthOfBubble numberOfHeight:heightOfBubble condition: NO];
```

And I got the following error;

```
Mar 19 00:55:45  BubbleText03[44457] <Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0. Backtrace:
  <+[BubbleText10 drawBubbleButtonWithText2:number:numberOfWidth:numberOfHeight:condition:]+4941>
   <-[BubbleView drawRect:]+421>
    <-[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:]+83>
     <-[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:]+67>
      <-[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:]+444>
       <-[UISlider endTrackingWithTouch:withEvent:]+255>
        <-[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:]+620>
         <-[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:]+2747>
          <-[UIWindow sendEvent:]+4011>
           <-[UIApplication sendEvent:]+371>
            <__dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue+3248>
             <__handleEventQueue+4879>
              <__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__+17>
               <__CFRunLoopDoSources0+556>
                <__CFRunLoopRun+918>
                 <CFRunLoopRunSpecific+420>
                  <GSEventRunModal+161>
                   <UIApplicationMain+159>
                    <main+111>
                     <start+1>
```

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `@selector(drawRect:)` use `@selector(setNeedsDisplay)`.

---

Documentation:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect;
```

> … This method is called when a view is first displayed or when an event occurs that invalidates a visible part of the view. **You should never call this method directly yourself.** To invalidate part of your view, and thus cause that portion to be redrawn, call the `setNeedsDisplay` or `setNeedsDisplayInRect:` method instead.

Even if it says *directly yourself* and you are not calling it directly yourself, it still applies to your case.

<sub>— PaintCode Support</sub>

Comment: It worked like a charm! Thank you so much for sharing your ability!!